# How to find last non-blank entry given a case-insensitive unique identifier?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that is autofilled from a google form. A person is allowed to do the questionnaire as often as they'd like, but I would like to not make them answer every question every time. Every time they fill out the questionnaire they must provide their identity.

I've created an example of a similar sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z2RLowhb2_Ts8OyKYItnP6AwtTdBEr6wX4Tsj8vKxGk/edit?usp=sharing).

In this case I have 3 users apple, orange, and banana. Each has both a price and an amount. What I want to do is find each unique case insensitive name, and their most recent input in each column. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter out empty rows,Sort in reverse and vlookup:

E3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(PROPER(A3:A11)))
```

F3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(E3:E5,SORT(FILTER({A3:B11,ROW(A3:A11)},B3:B11<>""),3,0),2,0))
```

G3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(E3:E5,SORT(FILTER({A3:C11,ROW(A3:A11)},C3:C11<>""),4,0),3,0))
```